# Ninjaforms - Query submissions by user

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

I've set up a Ninjaforms file upload form and it's working well. However, I'm creating a user dashboard and I want to be able to display submissions in the front-end by users: Logged in users will be able to review their file submissions. I've tried using variations on Ninja_Forms()->form( $form_id ) but to no avail.

Comment: You can try in a custom way, for example, directly query on your db table.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.